# Validating data on table using before insert trigger

Tags: mysql

I have a table, person having the following columns:

```
id
name
lastname
dob (date of birth)
city
```

I want to use a before insert trigger on the table to perform validation of the data entered: - id must be 13 digits - name should be valid name (for instance, it should contain no digits) - dob should be in the format 'yyyy/mm/dd'

How do I do this?

Comment: ID should be auto-increment and DOB should be of type DATE.

Comment: id not auto increment ,entered by user but it must be 13 digit

Comment: yes DOB is Date data type